# TikZ graph with interesting vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs

I'd like to use TikZ to typeset some graphs like this one:

[image: graph with interesting vertices]

(Sorry for the crappy camera-phone pic)

I am familiar with `\node`, `\path` and `edge`, as well as with getting different arrowhead styles.

The bit that's tripping me up is getting the vertices of the graph to be these little triangular number diagrams. This one is relatively simple (the number diagrams are only 2x2), but I have others where the diagrams are 3x3 and bigger.

Would it be best to use an `array` environment inside each `\node`? Is that even possible?

Or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: It is certainly possible to use `array` in a node. That sounds like  a good idea for this graph. If you try this and have trouble, I suggest posting a MWE.

Answer (score 8):

The new graph drawing library in the CVS version of `pgf` can do this quite nicely. Exploiting the `align` key, and setting it to `right` means the node contents in this specific case can be given quite simply.

However, it does  needs `luatex` to compile.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={align=right}]

\graph [layered layout,grow=up, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        "00\\0" -> "01\\0" -> {"01\\1", "11\\0"} -> "11\\1"
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's neat, and impressive. I may look into updating my system to try and use these new features. I appreciate your time.